# how to get font color of a XSSF CELLSTYLE?

Tags: apache-poi, xssf

I am trying to get  font color of cell of a XLSX file.
I am using the apache poi.
I am able to get the cell color but not the font color.
Any kind of suggestion will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From an [XSSFCellStyle](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html) you can [get](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#getFont%28%29) the [XSSFFont](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFont.html). From that, you can [get](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFont.html#getXSSFColor%28%29) the [XSSFColor](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html). Finally, from the XSSFColor, you can get the colour information as [ARGB Hex](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html#getARGBHex%28%29), [RGB with Tint](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html#getRgbWithTint%28%29) etc.

Your code would look something like:

```
XSSFCellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
XSSFFont font = style.getFont();
XSSFColor colour = font.getXSSFColour();
System.out.println("The colour is " + colour.getARGBHex());
```

Comment: I'm getting null back as color when I call font.getXSSFColour(). I can call getColor() and get a pallete index number (8 if that is significant).  The cell has no empty string content.  Any ideas how I can get a rgb from the pallete index?